# I’m trying to remove a flush mount LED ceiling light to install a ceiling fan. It won’t come off

Tags: electrical, lighting, removal

There are no notches in the housing. I have pulled down to no avail. I have rotated it counterclockwise and it spins endlessly. Even the light cover spins both directions. How do I remove this light fixture?

[image: light fixture]

Comment: Can you pry out that translucent diffuser at its edge? Alternatively just pull forcefully on the edge of the fixture and it maycome loose. Another possibility is to use a mirror to examine the space between the housing and the ceiling looking for a release mechanism such as a spring tab.

Comment: I tried. It bent the plastic a bit, but didn’t budge. I didn’t want to break it.

Comment: Another possibility is to insert a prybar or heavy screwdriver between the ceiling and the fixture. If you do this insert a putty knife or sheet metal to protect the ceiling.

Comment: I’ll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Where is this? What country?

Comment: If the "light cover" spins in the housing it should be possible to pry it out. Try a suction cup or vacuum cleaner on the edge and pull steadily. Or insert one thin implement and then another next to it and sweep one of them. Like getting a bicycle tire off a rim.

Comment: I’m in the US. The light cover doesn’t actually sit in a notch. I can run my fingernail between the cover and the black frame all the way around. This fixture is stumping me!!

Comment: If you push the diffuser in the center, does it deform inward? You might push inward and rotate and see if that releases something.

Comment: Everything comes off with a big enough hammer or screwdriver....

Answer (score 3):

Look at 'Project Source' light fixture from Lowes. It looks the same. To take fixture down, twist counter-clockwise. If it spins, I'm thinking the fixture mount was attached to a swivel-mount and not directly to the box. The swivel may be doing the spin. With the POWER OFF, get something flat and slip it between fixture and ceiling to hold the swivel-mount steady while turning the fixture counterclockwise.

possible swivel-mount:
[image: Swivel-mount]

Fixture mount:
[image]
[image]